# Is there an event that is fired when a Facebook friend logs in?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Is it possible to know when one of your Facebook friends logs in to Facebook? Getting a list of friends is easy enough, but that doesn't tell you their online status. Getting their chat status is a lot of work, is unreliable, and the user may be logged in but not have chat turned on.

So i was wondering if Facebook fires some event that can be trapped letting me know that one of my friends (or any arbitrary user_id, I guess) has logged in (or logged out, for that matter).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Apart from the chat API there is nothing that I know of. And from a user perspective I would not want that – it’s not any 3rd-party app’s business to know when I am online, if I am not even _using_ that app but only one of my friends is …

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @CBroe. And I agree with you in usual circumstances. In our case, it's more a collaboration app, so there's some expectation that others in the group would want to know when you're online or not. Yep, sounds like chat is the only way. Thanks again!